# Multiplicative groups of nonzero rational and real numbers: Isomorphic or not?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Are the multiplicative groups $Q^*$ and $R^*$ isomorphic or not?

I have seen some solution talking about cardinality. How is cardinality related to whether they are isomorphic?

Comment: They aren't even isomorphic as sets.

Comment: Two structures cannot be isomorphic unless they both have the same cardinality. Remember that an isomorphism is a particular kind of bijection. But if any kind of bijection at all exists between two sets, then they have the same cardinality.

Comment: Can u give an example where I can say that there is no element in Q* which can be mapped to R*

Answer (score 7):

An isomorphism is a bijection. If there is a bijection between two sets, they have the same cardinality.

So, therefore, isomorphic objects (such as multiplicative groups, here) always have the same cardinality. And the contrapositive: objects with different cardinality cannot be isomorphic.

Answer (score 3):

They are not isomorphic. Suppose $f$ is an isomorfism from $\mathbb R^*$ to $\mathbb Q^*$.

Let $a$ be such that $f(a)=2$. There exists $b$ such that $b^3=a$. It follows $f(b)^3=f(b^3)=f(a)=2$. Contradiction.

Comment: Yes, a neat way of avoiding cardinality.